# Jupyter notebook not opening

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using anaconda installed with python 3.6.when i try opening jupyter notebook i keep getting this error[image: Error Message]

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you happen to try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Jupyter notebook;

`conda install notebook`